# Ansible 'package_facts' fails because "rpm" module cannot be imported

Tags: python, ansible, rpm, ansible-facts, sles

I'm trying to run this Ansible task to gather `package_facts`, but the task is failing on SLES 15 machines, but is working fine on SLES 12 machines.

```yaml
- name: Gathering facts
  ansible.builtin.package_facts: 
    manager: auto
```

I'm getting a warning on SLES 15 machines:

```yaml
[WARNING]: Found "rpm" but Failed to import the required Python library (rpm)
on SLES15's Python /usr/bin/python3.6. Please read module documentation
and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed,
but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the
documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```json
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not detect a supported package manager from the following list: ['pkg', 'portage', 'apt', 'rpm'], or the required Python library is not installed. Check warnings for details."}
```

Tried installing `rpm` in the Remote Node. But it's still failing.
And when I tried to import `rpm` module in python interactive shell, this is the error I'm getting:

```
"Failed to import system RPM module."
ImportError: Failed to import system RPM module. Make sure RPM Python bindings are installed on your system.
```

Comment: You can try to use `manager: zypper` or on the SLES 15 Remote Node `pip install rpm` as mentioned within the error message.

Comment: @U880D zypper is unsupported in package_facts. And I already installed `rpm` on the remote node, but it's still failing.

Comment: Ah, I see, according [the source code of `package_facts.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/package_facts.py) supported / implemented are `choices: ['auto', 'rpm', 'apt', 'portage', 'pkg', 'pacman', 'apk', 'pkg_info']` which are also reflected in actual docs [`package_facts` module – Package information as facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html) ... probably looked up an old one ...

Comment: Regarding "_I already installed RPM on the Remote Node_" the error message about `Failed to import the required Python library (rpm) on SLES15's Python /usr/bin/python3.6.` is quire clear. Is there are difference in the running environment or user in respect to the user which installed it?

Comment: @U880D I don't think so. 
I tried running `import rpm` in python interactive mode, and this is the error I'm getting: 
    `"Failed to import system RPM module. "
ImportError: Failed to import system RPM module. Make sure RPM Python bindings are installed on your system.`

Comment: But if even in interactive mode the error message says `ImportError: Failed to import system RPM module. Make sure RPM Python bindings are installed on your system.`, why "_don't think so._". What makes you believe the computer is wrong? Is than there are difference in the running environment or user in respect to the user which installed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the error message

```
Failed to import the required Python library (rpm) on SLES15's Python /usr/bin/python3.6. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed ...
```

means that the import of the already via `pip install rpm` installed Python RPM package failed and as you commented

> *I tried running `import rpm` in Python interactive mode, and this is the error I'm getting: `Failed to import system RPM module. ImportError: Failed to import system RPM module. Make sure RPM Python bindings are installed on your system.`*

because of missing [`python-rpm`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/python-rpm) bindings.

> *This package contains a module that permits applications written in the Python programming language to use the interface supplied by RPM Package Manager libraries. This package should be installed if you want to develop Python programs that will manipulate RPM packages and databases.*

It is documented within the [`package_facts` module – Package information as facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html) under [Requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html#requirements)

> *For SUSE-based systems `python3-rpm` package must be installed on Targeted Hosts. This package is required because SUSE does not include RPM Python bindings by default.*

and to resolve you'll probably need to do an additional `pip install python3-rpm`.